# Cakephp - find() function outputting query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

When using the find() function in methods CakePHP outputs the query like so:

```
`Query: SELECT `Fonyker`.`id`, `Fonyker`.`fonykid`, `Fonyker`.`email`, `Fonyker`.`username`,` etc
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: does it return the query or the data?

Comment: It prints out the query, there is not data

Comment: please add your exact call to the find() method to the question.

Comment: Found the problem, I made a modification to my model and i reverted the change in the database but didn't revert it in the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing your warnings.. Usually when there's a problem with a query, cake displays it like this:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: <your error> [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]

Query: SELECT `Fonyker`.`id`, `Fonyker`.`fonykid ....
```

It seems to me that you're just hiding the Warning (maybe in the php configuration or in cake's configuration?)

try to run the query directly in the database and check if there are any errors

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm not suppressing anything as far as I know, where can I check to see if error_reporting is set?

Comment: if you haven't touched anything in the core files, then i have no idea why it's not displaying the warnings, usually the config is in the core.php : `Configure::write('debug', 2);` or maybe the error is beeing displayed but its hidden by some css.. you'll need to debug and test to find the problem =) cheers